# Select databases which only contain specific table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm looking for a way to select all databases on my sql server, which only contain the table "dbo.mytable"

How can i do this ?

I already have these two sql queries :

```
Select name From sys.databases Where database_id > 5
```

And

```
IF EXISTS
    (SELECT * FROM sys.objects 
    WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[mytable]') AND type in (N'U')) 
  Select 1 [Exists]
Else
  Select 0 [Exists]
```

The first query, lists all databases on my sql server, and the second checks if dbo.mytable exists. I would like to merge them.

Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A concise way that brings them all back in one resultset is

```
SELECT name
FROM   sys.databases
WHERE  CASE
         WHEN state_desc = 'ONLINE' 
              THEN OBJECT_ID(QUOTENAME(name) + '.[dbo].[mytable]', 'U')
       END IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Msg 942, Level 14, State 4, Line 1
Database '...' cannot be opened because it is offline.

Comment: It's a good solution, but also need add this: state_desc != 'OFFLINE'

Comment: @Devart - Good point. Probably best just to look at ones that are explicitly online.

Comment: +1 i dont know how to thank you. you have done gr8 work for me by this query.

Comment: instead of 'state_desc' filtering it is possible to use 'state' = 0 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178534.aspx

Comment: Plus one for a clever solution :)

Comment: @MikaelEriksson 

Answer (score 4):

You can use `sp_Msforeachdb` that is an undocumented Stored procedure and run on all databases :

```
EXEC sp_Msforeachdb "use [?];select * from sys.tables where name='MYTable' "
```

more about sp_msforeachtable : [The undocumented sp_MSforeachdb procedure](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/joew/archive/2008/08/27/60700.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

Return list of databases, which contains the specified table -

**Query:**

```
DECLARE 
      @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
    , @table_name SYSNAME

SELECT @table_name = 'dbo.test'

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#db_temp') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #db_temp 

CREATE TABLE #db_temp (db_nm SYSNAME)

SELECT @SQL = (
    SELECT '
        USE [' + d.name + ']; 

        INSERT INTO #db_temp (db_nm)
        SELECT DB_NAME()
        WHERE EXISTS(
            SELECT 1
            FROM sys.objects
            WHERE [object_id] = OBJECT_ID(''' + @table_name + ''')
                AND [type] = ''U''
        )'
    FROM sys.databases d
    WHERE d.name NOT IN ('master', 'tempdb', 'model', 'msdb')
        AND d.state_desc != 'OFFLINE'
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')

EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL

SELECT * 
FROM #db_temp dt
```

**Output:**

```
USE [...]; 

INSERT INTO #db_temp (db_nm)
SELECT DB_NAME()
WHERE EXISTS(
    SELECT 1
    FROM sys.objects
    WHERE [object_id] = OBJECT_ID('...')
        AND [type] = 'U'
)

...
```