# Display all the names of databases containing particular table

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I have many databases in my SQL Server.

I have to just search for database names containg particular table name `Heartbitmaster`

I have many databases such as `Gotgold`, `DVD`, etc and I just want to find database names from query that contain this table `Heartbitmaster`.

I searched I tried for query:

```
SELECT 
    TABLE_NAME  
FROM 
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
WHERE 
    TABLE_TYPE = 'base table'   
    AND table_schema = 'Heartbitmaster'
```

but it didn't work.

I searched further and came across:

```
SELECT name, database_id, create_date
FROM sys.databases
```

but dont know how to arrange further where condition for search of table name

Please help me.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

I got it done through following query:

```sql
SELECT name
FROM sys.databases
WHERE  CASE WHEN state_desc = 'ONLINE' 
         THEN OBJECT_ID(QUOTENAME(name) + '.[dbo].[heartbit]', 'U')
       END IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Of course, this won't find any table called `heartbit` which is in a schema different from `dbo`.

Comment: I JUST WANTED TO FIND db NAME CONTAINIING TABLE HEARTBIT

Comment: there's no need to shout - I was just pointing out a limitation. The query may work in your circumstances, but may not be suitable for future visitors to this question.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever no - no , my caps lock was on and i was unaware of it..This is not intentional. You can see i was trying to write DB in capital letters, for that i pressed shift key, but oppositely its turned into small letter.

Comment: @MikaelEriksson i am working with new small keyboard whos keys are not fit in my hands so somewhere for pressing 'a' key i might have pressed 'capslock'

Comment: No worries. +1 for a clever solution.

Comment: You can use `OBJECT_ID(QUOTENAME(name) + '..[heartbit]', 'U')` (without schema) to use the user default schema

Comment: @MikaelEriksson - Unfortunate that it was copied from here though https://stackoverflow.com/a/16520904/73226

Answer (score 22):

```
sp_MSforeachdb 'SELECT "?" AS DB, * FROM [?].sys.tables WHERE name like ''%tablename%'''
```

try this one

Comment: In my case, as most tables do not have default schema (dbo), I prefer this method. The downside is that it generates a line for each database. May have to scroll to bottom to reveal the one you need.

Answer (score 5):

I needed something slightly different.

This will return all tables and their corresponding DBs with names containing the supplied string:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME, TABLE_SCHEMA 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
WHERE TABLE_NAME like '%_<insert_name_here>';
```

Comment: Your scenario is a situation developers frequently find themselves in but is not really related to the OP's goal. **For anyone reading this, if it's not clear, this finds `tables`, not `databases` that match the criteria.**

Comment: Wait, did't OP ask: "I have many databases[...]and I just want to find database names from query that contain this table Heartbitmaster."?   The way I understood it, OP is trying to find the DB(s) that contain tables with the name 'Heartbitmaster'

Comment: Right so the solution he desired and found did that. It found databases *that contained* the tables. Your solution only finds any tables within a database, if that makes sense.

Comment: My solution returns two columns:  TABLE_NAME  and TABLE_SCHEMA.    The latter field denotes upon which DB the former can be found, if I am not mistaken?

Comment: @laus102 This won't work for MSSQL, but possible for an RDBMS with different paradigm like Oracle. In MSSQL schema i contain with a db and then holds table, so this only search a single DB and returns all schema within that have the table.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to find database objects (e.g. tables, columns, triggers) by name - have a look at the **FREE** Red-Gate tool called [SQL Search](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-search/) which does this - it searches your entire database for any kind of string(s).

[image]

[image]

It's a great must-have tool for any DBA or database developer - did I already mention it's absolutely **FREE** to use for any kind of use??

As for the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` or the SQL Server specific catalog views: as far as I know, those are always constrained to the current database you're in - so you cannot search across all databases on your server. SQL Search does this for you - by searching into every single database on the server.

Comment: i have been asked to make the query

Comment: @NavatKayAahe: as I said - I don't believe you can do this in one single query. Yes, you can get a list of databases from `sys.databases` - but then you'd need to iterate over this list, go to each database separately, and inspect it's `(database).sys.tables` catalog view.

Answer (score 1):

Create Procedure as bellow

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_FindTableNameInAllDatabase
@TableName VARCHAR(256)
AS
DECLARE @DBName VARCHAR(256)
DECLARE @varSQL VARCHAR(512)
DECLARE @getDBName CURSOR
SET @getDBName = CURSOR FOR
SELECT name
FROM sys.databases
CREATE TABLE #TmpTable (DBName VARCHAR(256),
SchemaName VARCHAR(256),
TableName VARCHAR(256))
OPEN @getDBName
FETCH NEXT
FROM @getDBName INTO @DBName
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
SET @varSQL = 'USE ' + @DBName + ';
INSERT INTO #TmpTable
SELECT '''+ @DBName + ''' AS DBName,
SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) AS SchemaName,
name AS TableName
FROM sys.tables
WHERE name LIKE ''%' + @TableName + '%'''
EXEC (@varSQL)
FETCH NEXT
FROM @getDBName INTO @DBName
END
CLOSE @getDBName
DEALLOCATE @getDBName
SELECT *
FROM #TmpTable
DROP TABLE #TmpTable
GO
EXEC usp_FindTableNameInAllDatabase 'Address'
GO 

exec usp_FindTableNameInAllDatabase 'user'
```

Comment: thank for answer but above simple query which i have posted as a answer worked.

Answer (score 0):

It Works!!!!!!! 
Run this query for finding database name for a particular table
The paste table name in @tablename

Drop table #tempo for next time run

```
declare @tablename varchar(max) = 'patient'
declare @count int = (select max(database_id) FROM   sys.databases)
declare @n int = 1
declare @dbname varchar(max)
declare @query nvarchar(max)
create table #tempo(Databasename varchar(max), tablename varchar(max))
while @n <= @count
begin
select @dbname = name from sys.databases where database_id = @n and service_broker_guid <> '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'
set @query = 'insert into #tempo(Databasename,tablename) select '''+@dbname+''' [Database],name from '+@dbname+'.sys.tables where name like ''%'+@tablename+'%'''
exec(@query)
set @n=@n+1;
end
select * from #tempo
```

At the last giving error like

> Database 'databasename' cannot be opened because it is offline.

then run this query separately

```
select * from #tempo
```

Answer (score 0):

I Complete  sp_MSforeachdb and create a procedure like this :

```
create PROCEDURE findTableName
@tablename nvarchar(max) 
AS
BEGIN
    declare @sqlCommand nvarchar(max) 
    CREATE TABLE #t (DBName VARCHAR(256),SchemaName VARCHAR(256),TableName VARCHAR(256))
    set @sqlCommand='insert into #t (DBName,SchemaName,TableName) exec sp_MSforeachdb ''SELECT "?" AS DB, SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) AS SchemaName ,name FROM [?].sys.tables WHERE name like ''''%'+@tablename+'%'''''''
    --print @sqlCommand
    exec ( @sqlCommand)
    select * from #t
END
```