# Display all the names of databases containing particular table contain the _BKP and table record count and their sizes

Tags: sql-server

In our environment, we have more than 60 databases in the SQL Instance. The developer created the _BKP tables and forgot to drop them, causing the database sizes to grow and get a low disk size.
I want a SQL Code to search the table name containing _BKP across all the databases in the SQL Instance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Display all the names of databases containing particular table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18141547/display-all-the-names-of-databases-containing-particular-table)

Comment: No, I am looking for row count and Table size as well.

Comment: [SQL count rows in a table](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28917736/2029983)

Comment: As I am looking for across all databases.

Comment: Yes, you would combine the 2 duplicates. Use the solution for going through the databases with the solution for getting row counts from the `sys` objects.

Comment: This code will give the information about the objects contains _BKP, I also need the row count and object size in MB's (sp_MSforeachdb 'SELECT "?" AS DB, * FROM [?].sys.tables WHERE name like ''%_BKP''')

Comment: Yes, see the prior linked answer: [SQL count rows in a table](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28917736/2029983); then you just need to alter your SQL appropriately.

Comment: I tried to alter it but needed help to generate the correct output. If you have it handy, can you please provide the script?

Comment: Not enough effort by OP to solve their own problem. Question is too broad. This is not a coding service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than using `sp_msforeachdb` I build my own query here, but the method is still the same; build a query that queries each database and use the solution from the other linked answer ([SQL count rows in a table](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28917736/2029983)) to get the counts for each table:

```
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX),
        @CRLF nchar(2) = NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10);

DECLARE @Delimiter nvarchar(50) = @CRLF + N'UNION ALL' + @CRLF;

SELECT @SQL = STRING_AGG(CONVERT(nvarchar(MAX),N'') +
                         N'SELECT N' + QUOTENAME(d.[name],'''') + N' AS DatabaseName,' + @CRLF + 
                         N'       OBJECT_NAME(p.object_id) AS ObjectName,' + @CRLF + 
                         N'       SUM([rows])' + @CRLF + 
                         N'FROM sys.partitions p' + @CRLF + 
                         N'WHERE OBJECT_NAME(p.object_id) LIKE ''%[_]BKP''' + @CRLF +
                         N'  AND p.index_id in (0,1)' + @CRLF +
                         N'GROUP BY p.object_id',@Delimiter) + N';'
FROM sys.databases d;

--PRINT @SQL; --Your debugging best friend

EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL;
```

Comment: I have the SQL Version of 2012, and the STRING_AGG function was not available in 2012.

Comment: 2012 is *completely* unsupported, @PavanKumar ; if you are using unsupported technology you should be letting people know that in the question. You'll need to amend the above to use the "old" `FOR XML PATH` (and `STUFF`) method.

Comment: Agree with you, and soon we are migrating to 2016.

Comment: Why 2016? That only has just a few years of *extended* support left.

Comment: It's a management decision.