# Is the SQL database_id value reused?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

When I run the query below, I get the database_id field for each database. I am under the impression that the value is being reused. For example, I delete databases, then I restore new databases. The database_id value for some of those newly restored databases may be an old one.
Is that possible? Can that be changed?

The reason why I ask is the following. I am running a query across each DB in the SQL server. I would like to exclude some DBs and I am using the database_id field to identify those I wish to skip in the query. However, if a database_id is being reused, I must to update the query regularly.
Thank you.

```
SELECT *
FROM sys.databases
```

Comment: It's not persistent so it can be changed.

Comment: `database_id` values may be reused as databases are dropped/created/restored. This is not configurable behavior. Consider adding why you care about this to your question so someone can suggest a solution.

Comment: @DanGuzman
thank you, I edited the question and presented the scenario. Sounds like I should use the database name instead.

Comment: @DeepDiver, I agree it would be better to use the name.

Comment: @DeepDiver As I say before do not use the `database_id`, imaging you have A db and you delete it, then create B db and create also A db. Then you are in trouble if you use `database_id`

Comment: @Sami
thanks to you and DanGuzman, it is all very clear, now. Learnt something new.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Database_id could change so you should use `DB_ID` function to get correct value before doing any type of comparison.

> [DB_ID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/db-id-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)
>
> This function returns the **database identification (ID) number** of a specified database.
>
> ```
> DB_ID ( [ 'database_name' ] )
> ```

For instance:

```
SELECT *
FROM sys.master_files
WHERE database_id = DB_ID('my_database_name');

-- instead of
SELECT *
FROM sys.master_files
WHERE database_id = 18;  -- database_id may not exists or point to different db
```

Comment: Thank you, I had something similar to `SELECT * FROM sys.databases WHERE database_id NOT IN (6,7,8,11,19)` but clearly cannot do that.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I will do and solves my situation.

Using the solution suggested [in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16519663/select-databases-which-only-contain-specific-table), I will run a subquery and create a list of all databases where the target table exists. Then, I run my query across all those DBs available in that list.